# Gender-neutral -x in adjectives of nationality

Tags: neutralidad-de-género

Yesterday I was trying to gather my thoughts on how I might translate a form from English to the Spanish typical of Spanish-speakers in New Orleans, and I thought about the gender-inclusive suffix "-x." I know that it is appropriate to use "-x" whenever "-a" in the feminine alternates with "-o" in the masculine. However, there are other situations where "a-" appears in the feminine, but what appears in the masculine is neither "-o" nor "-a."

The first is in nouns and adjectives that end in "-e" in the masculine and "-a" in the feminine. Since "-x" can stand for any alternation between vowels, it does just fine in this instance. It also does fine in the situation of plurals of adjectives of nationality: the word "españolxs" can be seen as "-xs" standing in the place of either "-es" or "-as."

My question concerns the SINGULAR of adjectives of nationality whose stem ends in a consonant such that the masculine form of these adjectives is identical to the stem: "español." However, the feminine still adds the "-a": "española." My question is: Is it appropriate to write "españolx?" Have you seen "españolx," "francesx," "alemanx," or anything similar?

Comment: Typical Spanish-speakers of New Orleans??

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple, don't hurt your brain, the inclusive form doesn't exist in the Spanish language, at least officially according to the RAE.

[image]

<sub>[Tweet link](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1007607107083014144?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%22%3EJune%2015,%202018%3C/a%3E%3C/blockquote%3E%20%3Cscript%20async%20src=%22https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js%22%20charset=%22utf-8%22%3E%3C/script%3E)</sub>

Comment: Don't break your mind? ;-) I will look for an equivalence = Don't hurt your brain

Comment: Don't give yourself a headache. :)

Comment: Great, thanks 